# Some good starting hands in 6 card omaha

Tags: omaha

Strictly for 6 card plo -
What are some good pre flop starting hands ?
Are kings better than aces ?
Are triple suited connectors better than aces ?

Is there any equity calculator available for 6 card plo ?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.pokervip.com/strategy-articles/pot-limit-omaha-plo/6-max-plo-basic-starting-hand-chart What about this? https://www.pokerlistings.com/strategy/potlimit-omaha-starting-hands

Comment: I'll post an answer later, but things that have the potential to flop the nuts are extremely strong starting hands in 6-card PLO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the things to look for in a good starting hand in 6 card plo in no particular order.

- suits: having 3 suits (especially Ax of a suit)
- connectedness: cards that are in order (ex. 56789T)
- pairs: potential to make a set, or maybe an overpair on a board with no possible straights or flushes
- rank: higher cards are better and applies to all of the above. higher straights, flushes, pairs will make it more likely you win the hand and possibly even make a slightly better hand than your opponent with a lot of action

I believe that the best possible or close to the best hand would be AAKKQQ with 3 suits. Hands like KQJT98 with 3 suits are also extremely strong if not better.

Answer (score 0):

Best hand is A♦️K♦️A♣️10♣️J♠️Q♠️